# How to extract a react router parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-parameters

I have a project where the only way to update the page is to write a value in the url (let's say it has to be that way). The value should get extracted and sent as a parameter in a rest call. I don't seem to find the way to set the route on App.js and manage to take out the url parameter.

My App.js:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getParam()
    //rest call code

  })
  return (   
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/:date"/>
        <Head />
        <div className="page-wrap">
          <Header className="header"/>
          <Main />
          <Footer className="footer"/>
        </div>
      
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function getParam(){
    let {date} = useParams
    console.log(date)
    return({date})
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useParams` hook in a function component:

```
export default function Main() {
  let { date } = useParams();
  console.log("date from route: ", date)
  return <>I am Main Component</>
}
```

when you have router setup as:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/some-date-here"/>
      <Route exact path="/:date">
        <Head />
        <div className="page-wrap">
          <Header className="header"/>
          <Main />
          <Footer className="footer"/>
        </div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Funny part is that the moment I finish the adaptation you make an edit(not a problem of course).  In this version you basically just made a new layer (DateComp) between my code and the App.js right?

Comment: First of all, thank you for all the effort up until now. The only problem that I have is that now I don't have a default page, meaning when I don't have /date nothing shows up. And I need the default page there. I tried removing the exact property from <Route> but still nothing shows up.

Comment: You can put a Redirect to handle that. Check my edit.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you for all the help, really means a lot!

Comment: By any chance do you know, if I now make a rest call from for example the <Header> using that url parameter, can I use the data in <Main>? If not, do I have to make a new layer of abstraction between App.js and the other components and make a rest call there?