# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an error when dispatching project details by its ID (`match.params.id`), I am new to React. What is the best way to solve this issue?

```
   const ProjectDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { loading, error, project } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.projectDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjectDetails(match.params.id));

    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, match.params.id]);

  return ()
}
```

Comment: `match?.params?.id && dispatch(getProjectDetails(match.params.id));` if there is no `id`, do something you need to

Comment: Use `useParams` hook. An example: [How to extract a react router parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282154/2873538)

Comment: @zixiCat That probably wouldn't be a great idea, it would call `dispatch` with `undefined`.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `match` is `undefined`. Since we can only guess at what `match` is, it's hard for us to help you. If it's correct that it can be `undefined`, you'll want to test for that (using an `if`, for instance). If it's not correct that it can be `undefined`, then you need to find the bug that makes it `undefined` sometimes, which will be in other code that isn't in the question.